# Не могу получить Country и Code

Tags: php, mysql, объекты, redbeanphp

Не могу получить данные Country и Code

```
$query = R::findAll('country');
var_dump($query);

object(RedBeanPHP\OODBBean)#18 (10) {   ["properties":protected]=>   array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["Code"]=>
    string(3) "ABW"
    ["Name"]=>
    string(5) "Aruba"   }   ["__info":protected]=>   array(7) {
    ["type"]=>
    string(7) "country"
    ["sys.id"]=>
    string(2) "id"
    ["sys.orig"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["Code"]=>
      string(3) "ABW"
      ["Name"]=>
      string(5) "Aruba"
    }
    ["tainted"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["changed"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["changelist"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["model"]=>
    NULL   }   ["beanHelper":protected]=>   object(RedBeanPHP\BeanHelper\SimpleFacadeBeanHelper)#11 (0) {   }   ["fetchType":protected]=>   NULL   ["withSql":protected]=>   string(0) ""   ["withParams":protected]=>   array(0) {   }   ["aliasName":protected]=>   NULL   ["via":protected]=>   NULL   ["noLoad":protected]=>   bool(false)   ["all":protected]=>   bool(false) }
```

$query[1]->id получаю строку с 1, при $query[1]->Code или $query[1]->Name получаю NULL.
Как быть?

Comment: UPD: Решено! В БД указал названия с маленькой буквы и заработало!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPD: Решено! В БД указал названия с маленькой буквы и заработало